# How to add redirect on shopify page while also insuring all information is correctly filled out

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, liquid

I have tried to add a customer redirect at the end of a shopify registration form. It will successfully redirect customers but they are able to incorrectly fill out the form and/or leave sections blank. If I remove the redirect it there will be errors in the form if the customer does not fill it out correctly. I have tried these two ways (plus everything Chatgpt recommended) but none have worked.

`<input type="hidden" name="return_to" value="/account/addresses">`

and

```
<script> 
 (function() { 
 var REDIRECT_PATH = '/account/addresses'; 

 var selector = '#create_customer, form[action$="/account"][method="post"]', 
     $form = document.querySelectorAll(selector)[0]; 

 if ($form) { 
   $redirect = document.createElement('input'); 
   $redirect.setAttribute('name', 'return_to'); 
   $redirect.setAttribute('type', 'hidden'); 
   $redirect.value = REDIRECT_PATH; 
   $form.appendChild($redirect); 
 } 
   })(); 
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the form is submitted, it is handled by Shopify's backend.
Then it refreshes the page with new information of the response.

I don't believe you could manually send this form using Javascript.
You could however check (using the liquid form object) whether or not the form was submitted successfully, then redirect via Javascript.

```
{% if form.posted_successfully? %}
  <script>
    window.location.assign(/* url */);
  </script>
{% endif %}
```

Note that this a workaround and that the client will be redirected twice, once when you submit the form and another time using Javascript.